# Planning to replace hid bulb to led H1 connector

Tags: honda, headlight, led, hid, city

I have Honda city 2016 model (Indian version). 
I had changed the factory halogen bulbs to AES projector with H1 connector type.

Recently one of my hid 5000k bulb gone bad. I'm planning to replace the existing hid bulb to LED bulb.

Question 1: Will that work? Can I replace my hid bulb to LED bulb?
Question 2: Is there any connector different between hid and led?

Answer (score 2):

LED bulbs will not give the light output (lumens) needed for good vision at night. The "ordinary" halogen bulbs you replaced are better than LED for lighting up the road at distance at the moment, however this could, and probably will, change in the not too distant future. Stick to replacing the HID with another HID or go back to halogen.

Comment: Can you suggest a best HID Bulb. I tried kensun hid kit with 6000K. 
But, i am not so impressed. i drive a lot in City.

Comment: I bought Sun Wolf.... but buying advice is not what the site is about.

Comment: Why do you now have 6000k? In your original post you say 5000k, there is a difference.

Comment: which gives more light and visiblity during the ride 5000K or 6000K ? 
I've already tried 6000K but when i compare the light with Benz or audi my 6000K is less.

So, thought to try 6000K.

Comment: You say 6000k is less but then you try it... have you any idea?